# Attempt to read property "title" on bool (View: D:\Project 2021\LARAVEL PROJECT\portfolio-app\resources\views\pages\posts.blade.php)

Tags: boolean, syntax-error, laravel-8

This is my controller :

```
  public function single(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $item = Blog::with(['users'])->where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
    return view('pages.posts', [
        'item' => $item
    ]);
}
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/single/{slug}', [HomeController::class, 'single'])->name('single');
```

and this is my blade:

```
  @foreach ($item as $item)
      <div class="col-lg-12 ftco-animate">
        <h2 class="mb-3">{{ $item->title }}</h2>
        <div><span class="icon-calendar"></span><span class="ml-2">Published {{ $item->created_at }}</span><span></span> <span class="icon-person ml-2"></span><span class="ml-2">{{ $item->users->name }}</span></div>
        <p>{!! $item->content !!}</p>
      </div> 
      @endforeach
```

when I click the post, my post detail get an error like this--->

```
Attempt to read property "title" on bool (View: D:\Project 2021\LARAVEL PROJECT\portfolio-app\resources\views\pages\posts.blade.php)
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably the error is caused by the foreach loop as your function only return a single value but when you add a loop means you need to display more than one value unless you remove that loop

```
  <div class="col-lg-12 ftco-animate">
    <h2 class="mb-3">{{ $item->title }}</h2>
    <div><span class="icon-calendar"></span><span class="ml-2">Published {{ $item->created_at }}</span><span></span> <span class="icon-person ml-2"></span><span class="ml-2">{{ $item->users->name }}</span></div>
    <p>{!! $item->content !!}</p>
  </div>
```